# Несанкционированный доступ к временной папке Apache

Tags: apache, уязвимости, php

Какие могут быть способы доступа извне во временную папку `tmp` Апача?
Просто хотя бы чтение.
И также, надо ли предпринять меры для защиты?

Comment: Не думаю что это актуально в вашем случае, но мб кому-то будет  [интересно](http://hutpu4.net/linux-open-source/kriticheskaya-uyazvimost-v-phpmyadmin.html)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, спасибо, интересно)
Правда, мне это вряд ли поможет.

Comment: Закрывайте apache в chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый очевидный mysql инъекции с помощью load_file - 
[MySQL инъекции](http://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/407323.php).

Comment: А где эта папка по умолчанию вообще находится конкретно?